# Comprehensive List of Essential Software for General Developers on Mac and PC

Tags: html, c++, editor

This may seem like an odd request, but as a computer science student, I'm always running into apps that make doing a development task easier than the way I was doing it before.  Unfortunately, I tend to discover these apps long after doing things the hard way for far too long.  I'm only on mac, but I figured I'd include both Mac and PC for future reference (if I ever have both systems).

For me, a student of C++ programming, I'm currently religiously using just a few pieces of software on Mac:

- XCODE - IDE
- Atom - Text Editing, HTML, and a few other things
- Cyberduck - SFTP into my school's Linux system.
- Terminal - (Haven't tried iTerm2 yet or any other Terminal
  alternative)
- Go2Shell - quick folder navigation for Terminal

What other utilitarian apps do you guys find particularly helpful for you as developers?  Feel free to mention any software you may use to help your workflow.

I hope this question isn't too broad of a topic for S.O.  If so, please feel free to remove it.

Also I didn't know what tag to use for this topic, so if the mods need to move this thread to a more appropriate area, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your list does not look bad at all ;)

Most developers will have a basic set of tools such as:

1. **An IDE** (Integrated development environment,e.g. phpStorm, Aptana,etc..) - where you write your code.
2. **Various Compilers** (e.g. C\CPP compiler for a C\CPP developer, or a LESS compiler for a web developer, whatever you use in your daily work) - to compile your raw code\markup into an executable\usable format.
3. **A Debugger** - to debug your code.
4. **A Local development stack** (e.g. LAMP, used mainly by web developers) - to execute your code and see how it works, debug, etc..
5. **A Dependency management tool** - optional: if you have a big project with many dependencies.
6. **A Version control system** (such as Git, SVN, etc..) - to maintain your project as a proper code repository.
7. **An FTP client** (if you upload files to a server)

That is generally what you need to write software\applications, anything in addition to that is considered helpful but you don't really need it.

There are some fancy tools for lazy people, those tools can save you some time but the huge disadvantage is when you start to rely on those tools and then you stop understanding how things actually are constructed and work - which will make the maintaining of your software a nightmare.

The best thing is to know when to use "helper" tools, but not many of them, use them only if you have to, and do not get to the situation where you rely on them - because then if they have a bug or a mysterious flaw, you will be dead in the water until the next hotfix or patch comes out.

Good luck !